# SUM last N values with criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formula, sumifs

I have simple table that looks like this:

[image]

All i need is to SUM points for specific player (John) in his last 3 matches.

I was able to come with this formula:

```
SUMPRODUCT(LARGE((A2:B="John")*(C2:D);{1;2;3}))
```

The problem is that instead of what I was looking for, it sums the highest 3 values, that can be anywhere in that range.

Is there some similar formula, that can do only the last 3 matches?

Comment: It's not clear from your screenshot which way is "recent"? up or down?

Comment: Recent matches are down. There is slightly darker blue color highlighting the matches in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a SUMPRODUCT can get you there with some constructed arrays using a COUNTIFS() and ROW() to get the most recent 3.

This formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIFS(A:B,G2,ROW(A:B)*{1,1},">="&ROW(A:B)*{1,1})<=3)*(A:B=G2),C:D)
```

on [this sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y5S5KFRZAxoUCmSO-EunKYMeGAhNETzGcOPHlUN8NbE/edit?usp=sharing) I made seems to work.

Comment: That will do it. Thank you very much, it's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Nice formula Matt!

Answer (score 1):

I thnk I have a formula that gives what you want.  It's not pretty, and I'm  sure it can be made simpler, but this works:

```
=query( query(
       { arrayformula(   {ROW(A1:A)         } ),
         query(A1:D,"select A, B, C, D",1)
       } , "select * order by Col1 desc",1),
 "select Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5    
  where (Col2 ='John' or Col3 = 'John')   
  order by Col1 desc limit 3",1)
```

Basically, it adds the row number as an extra column to the data, so that we can sort the data in reverse order by row number.  Then we query the result to find the first three occurences of 'John', in either Col A or Col B.

Here is a sample sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-mhTb5Cpp3D-1OltlmCfwlmM-vc2OknHxfJAyHD7BjI/edit?usp=sharing

Credit to Erik Tyler for a previous answer on a different question, on how to add the row number to a query.

Edit: Updated the sheet to provide the SUM of John's (or any player's) scores from the last three matches.  This can be combined with the previous formula, if you want a single formula to place somewhere.  Or will you have a list of all the players, and you'll want their last three scores beside each of their names?

If I can simplify the formula, I'll update it here.

Let me know if you need something more than this, or if this has answered your question.

Comment: So happy if it helped.  Matt's solution is very elegant, and I wish I knew how it worked. My knowledge on using arrays within formulas is not up to the task of understanding his method yet!  Lots to learn still...

Answer (score 0):

### Approach

I would use the query formula to get the cells that you need so that you can leverage the `limit` statement.

You should put a column with the indexes so that you can order the cells in descending order and take the first 3.

Given that your table headers are:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| INDEX | NAME 1 | NAME 2 | POINTS 1 | POINTS 2 |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I would use this query to get your desired result:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(QUERY(A2:E, "Select D * E where B = 'John' or C = 'John'" order by A desc limit 3"))
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to use your solution but query formula that you suggesting is not working. For some reason it returns this: https://i.imgur.com/NDvzhh9.png

Comment: I see that your formula is only the query. You should wrap the query in the `SUMPRODUCT` function like this: `=SUMPRODUCT( QUERY( ... ) )`.

Comment: Yes I did. There is a screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/NDvzhh9.png

Comment: Yes, for some reason it didn't load sorry.